# How to protect tomcat application - user authentication with fail2ban?

Tags: tomcat, java, fail2ban

AFAIK tomcat6 does not use Apache std .htaccess auth, but has own user authentication method.

My question is: How to protect it against brute force attack with fail2ban ?

Comment: You apply fail2ban rules on arbitrary logs using your own filters. Where's the problem? Please provide way more information.